# How to capture every SQL call made via .net Entity Framework 6.2

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Looking to capture and log every calls to the DB made by entity framework. What's the best way of doing this? is that the best way https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture it from the DB via the sys.processes

```
    With AllJobsRan(SPID,LastBatch,SourceProgram,HostName,LoginCredentials, script)
    as (
    select
        P.spid
    ,   P.last_batch
    ,   P.program_name
    ,   P.hostname
    ,   P.loginame
    ,   sql_handle
    from master.dbo.sysprocesses P
    where 
    --and      P.status not in ('background', 'sleeping')
    --and      P.cmd not in ('AWAITING COMMAND'
                        --,'MIRROR HANDLER'
                        --,'LAZY WRITER'
                        --,'CHECKPOINT SLEEP'
                        --,'RA MANAGER')
                        -- AND 
                        p.last_batch > '2/17/2020'
                        AND p.last_batch < '2/18/2020'
    ),
    Scripts(byteScript)
    as (
        select script from AllJobsRan
    )
select  
    AllJobsRan.SPID,
    AllJobsRan.LastBatch,
    AllJobsRan.HostName,
    AllJobsRan.LoginCredentials,
    LEN([SQLText].text) as [ScriptLength],
    [SQLText].text from AllJobsRan 
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(AllJobsRan.[script]) as [SQLText]
order by 
    LastBatch,[ScriptLength] desc
```

Comment: I am looking to capture this in code, not at the DB level.

Comment: Then, yes a wrapper is your best choice. The referenced methodology will work, however i'd recommend using a event based logic such as the one described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677160/in-entity-framework-how-to-call-a-method-on-entity-before-saving

Comment: To be more clear, you can intercept the information and log it however you want. If you want the exact queries getting ran, the DB is the most reliable method and you can retrieve past items and use them to fill your logs with historic information.

Answer (score 0):

REFERENCE: [Logging and intercepting database operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception)

You can set the `context.Database.Log` to `Console.Write`:

```
using (var context = new BlogContext())
{
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write;

    var blog = context.Blogs.First(b => b.Title == "One Unicorn");

    blog.Posts.First().Title = "Green Eggs and Ham";

    blog.Posts.Add(new Post { Title = "I do not like them!" });

    context.SaveChangesAsync().Wait();
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title]
    FROM [dbo].[Blogs] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (N'One Unicorn' = [Extent1].[Title]) AND ([Extent1].[Title] IS NOT NULL)
-- Executing at 10/8/2013 10:55:41 AM -07:00
-- Completed in 4 ms with result: SqlDataReader

SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title],
    [Extent1].[BlogId] AS [BlogId]
    FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[BlogId] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing at 10/8/2013 10:55:41 AM -07:00
-- Completed in 2 ms with result: SqlDataReader

UPDATE [dbo].[Posts]
SET [Title] = @0
WHERE ([Id] = @1)
-- @0: 'Green Eggs and Ham' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @1: '1' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing asynchronously at 10/8/2013 10:55:41 AM -07:00
-- Completed in 12 ms with result: 1

INSERT [dbo].[Posts]([Title], [BlogId])
VALUES (@0, @1)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Posts]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
-- @0: 'I do not like them!' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @1: '1' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing asynchronously at 10/8/2013 10:55:41 AM -07:00
-- Completed in 2 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```